# Display recursively all parent directories relative to the current one

Tags: bash, pwd

Display recursively all parent directories relative to the current one.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=/
for var in $(pwd)
do
echo "$var"
done
```

Comment: And your question would be ? What output do you expect ? What do you get ? What do you want ?

Comment: I did the right thing or not, or I can do otherwise

Comment: I would say not, then. IFS has no effect because nothing in there does word splitting. The `for` sees only one value, so it only loops once. The total outcome is equivalent to just running `pwd`. Nothing is called recursively. You should probably do otherwise, but who can tell?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, the `$(pwd)` undergoes split+glob as it's unquoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
(
  while
    [ "$PWD" != / ] && cd -P ..
  do
    pwd
  done
)
```

There exists however at least one pathological case where that code could run in an infinite loop: when the current directory has been deleted. In that case, I find that on GNU/Linux and with bash-5.0 at least, when bash it not interactive, `cd -P ..` outputs an error but does not return a failure exit status. Then, `$PWD` becomes `.` and subsequent `cd -P ..`'s do nothing. Changing the loop exit condition to  `[ "$PWD" != / ] && [ "$PWD" != . ] && cd -P ..`  works around the problem there.

Some comments about your approach:

- `$(pwd)` expands to the output of `pwd` minus the trailing newline characters, so it doesn't work properly if the current directory ends in newline characters.
- In POSIX shells `$PWD` holds a path to the current working directory, and that's what `pwd` prints. However note that unless you used `cd` with the `-P` option to get there, the path that's stored in `$PWD` and that `pwd` outputs may contain symlink components. If `$PWD` is `/foo/bar/baz` and that file is a symlink, then its parent directory may not be `/foo/bar`.
- in `bash`, leaving `$(pwd)` (or `$PWD`) unquoted in list context, such as in the `in` part of that `for` loop statement, invokes split+glob. You did configure the split part by setting `$IFS` to `/`, but forgot to disable the glob part (with `set -o noglob`). If `$PWD` was a directory called `/tmp/*`, that would have been split+globbed into "", "tmp" and all the non-hidden files in the current directory for instance.
- `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data. The way `bash` is commonly built and configured, in a directory called `/tmp/-Ene` the `echo -Ene` would output nothing. To output something followed by a newline, use `printf '%s\n' "$var"` instead.
- Even in the straight case of a `$PWD` being `/path/to/dir` none of its components being symlinks, your code outputs an empty line, `path`, `to` and `dir` none of which are ancestor directories of the current directory which are `/`, `/path` and `/path/to` instead.